# creating PKCS8 private keys with a PBMAC1 hash

Tags: public-key, pkcs8

[PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898) provides two encryption schemes (PBES1 and PBES2) and one message authentication scheme ([PBMAC1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-7.1)). It seems like a combined method (eg. authenticated encryption) would be ideal but whatever.

Anyway, my question is...  are there any tools in the wild that can create a PBMAC1 PKCS#8 encoded private key?

The man pages for OpenSSL make me think that OpenSSL doesn't support this:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkcs8

Answer (score 2):

Your link (2898) is actually PKCS**5** which defines those two encryption schemes (with predefined cases for 1) and the MAC scheme. [PKCS**8**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208) uses the ASN.1-flexible way (`AlgorithmIdentifier`) to identify the encryptionAlgorithm, but for specific values references the older PKCS5 **v1.5** which had only the scheme now called PBES1 and PBKDF1. OpenSSL also supports the PBES2/PBKDF2 schemes from PKCS5 v2 and the PBE schemes defined in PKCS12 (see below).
**PKCS8 does not support a separate authentication algorithm.** All defined PBES1 and PBES2 schemes and most pkcs12PBE ones do use CBC mode with padding, which provides some protection against accidental corruption but not tampering.

[PKCS**12**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292) is now the **more common and arguably better** way of transporting privatekeys plus usually related certificate(s). It **does have a PBMAC** on the whole container (technically optional but usually present) and PBE on the KeyBag and CertBag items in the container; even though certificates shouldn't need to be secret, by convention (or just custom) the CertBag is encrypted with weak 40-bit encryption, although OpenSSL has an undocumented option `-certpbe none` to leave it clear. PKCS12 originally referred to the older PKCS5 (effectively PBES1/PBKDF1) and added its own PBE/PBKDF scheme again with several predefined cases, plus its own PBMAC scheme. PKCS12 v1.1 changes this to prefer PBES2/PBKDF2 from newer PKCS5 for encryption while still documenting its own PBE schemes in Appendix C for backward compatibility, and still using its own PBMAC scheme.

If I had to speculate why the need for integrity protection wasn't appreciated at first, it might be that by 1990 most industry experience had been with wrapping *symmetric* keys, mostly for transport -- rarely storage, which was in special hardware instead -- and that customarily used a manually verified Key Check Value.